# Files not resolving and producing a 404 not Found MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I am coming from a webforms background and just used to being able to create folders to store my assets, but now I see its good practice to load everything into the content folder so I have created a folder under content/front-end-theme with my css and js files.

However it is given a 404 file not found even though the resources are their and included in the project. In webforms days i new i would have normally had to include runat=server is it the same for mvc.

In Source View its showing

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/front-end-theme/rs-plugin/css/settings.css")" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/front-end-theme/css/bootstrap.css")">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/front-end-theme/css/animate.css")">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/front-end-theme/css/prettyPhoto.css")">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/front-end-theme/css/carousel.css")">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/front-end-theme/style.css")">
<!-- COLORS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Url.Content("~/Content/front-end-theme/css/custom.css")>
```

I am using the following format to encode the source but as you see it doesnt appear to be appending the full url of localhost and that is the reason i think its not finddnd the js and css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/front-end-theme/css/prettyPhoto.css")">
```

Screen Shot to show my project layout.
[image]

Comment: You mention 'Source View', is that code present in e.g. `_Layout.cshtml`, or is it shown inside the web browser when doing View Source there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use *bundling and minification* to reduce the load time of your web pages, the number of requests to the server, and the size of requested assets.

**App_Start/BundleConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/css/bundles").Include(
        "~/Content/front-end-theme/rs-plugin/css/settings.css",
        "~/Content/front-end-theme/css/bootstrap.css",
        "~/Content/front-end-theme/css/animate.css",
        "~/Content/front-end-theme/css/prettyPhoto.css",
        "~/Content/front-end-theme/css/carousel.css",
        "~/Content/front-end-theme/style.css",
        "~/Content/front-end-theme/css/custom.css"
    ));
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@Styles.Render("~/css/bundles")
```

**Web.config**

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

You get the following HTML in Source View:

```
<link href="~/css/bundles?v=8DkUq-AixyqzByiFjkZ6JsVVx0oqXMUyZTjHBAozp8I1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

If you change `debug` to `true`, you get the following HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/front-end-theme/rs-plugin/css/settings.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/front-end-theme/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/front-end-theme/css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/front-end-theme/css/prettyPhoto.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/front-end-theme/css/carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/front-end-theme/style.css">
<!-- COLORS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/front-end-theme/css/custom.css">
```

Comment: When you say compression is this real time or is there a caching mechnisim in place here which you need to clear.